# angular-xeditable filter input and output data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular-xeditable: Im trying to find builtin input and output data filter.
I'v only found validator onbeforesave, onaftersave etc. But it is only validator, if I will change $data, it will not be saved.

Do you have any idea how to do input and output data filtering using xeditable?

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin methods.
The best way is to use not minified version of plugin, search for line:

```
self.save
```

and

```
self.show
```

And add extra lines,
it would be great if someone had added filter functions to the plugin.

In my case it is:

```
self.save = function() {
  var myData = angular.copy(self.scope.$data);
  myData = myData.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

  valueGetter.assign($scope.$parent, myData); 
};
```

insteed of:

```
self.save = function() {
     valueGetter.assign($scope.$parent, angular.copy(self.scope.$data));   
};
```